# Issue matching entries when importing into FeedMe with Craft4

Tags: plugin-feedme

I'm trying to import via JSON in feedMe, but entries aren't being matched for an entries field:

An `EntryType:Song` has a custom entries field of `EntryType:SourceTexts`

A `Song` has an additional custom field of `legacySongId`

A `SourceText` has an additional custom field of `legacyTranslationId`

The source texts and songs already exist, and I'm just trying to get the relationship in.

**Example JSON Import**

```
[
{
    "sourcetexts": [
        4872
    ],
    "songid": 3680
},
{
    "sourcetexts": [
        7794
    ],
    "songid": 3681
},
{
    "sourcetexts": [
        4875
    ],
    "songid": 3682
},
{
    "sourcetexts": [
        4874
    ],
    "songid": 3683
},
{
    "sourcetexts": [
        4873
    ],
    "songid": 3684
},
{
    "sourcetexts": [
        4813,
        5363
    ],
    "songid": 3686
},
{
    "sourcetexts": [
        4814,
        5364
    ],
    "songid": 3687
}]
```

**Relevant Feedme Mapping:**

[image: Relevant Feedme Mapping]

No other fields are imported.

**Example Log File**

```
info    Source Song Texts: Starting processing of node #4228.Show detail    19/02/2023 15:29
info    ↳ Source Song Texts: Match existing element with data {"legacySongId":6871}.    19/02/2023 15:29
info    ↳ Source Song Texts: Existing element #22674 found. 19/02/2023 15:29
info    ↳ Source Song Texts: Search for existing entry with query {"status":null,"sectionId":[null],"limit":null,"where":["=","field_legacyTranslationId_btjcagql",7786]}   19/02/2023 15:29
info    ↳ Source Song Texts: Found 0 existing entries: []   19/02/2023 15:29
info    ↳ Source Song Texts: Node #4228 skipped. No content has changed.
```

I'm sure this has worked before... It just can't find the entries by that legacy id for some reason.. Ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind, issue found - bug in Feedme when using a custom source. Switched the field back to running off a standard section and it appears to work now.